# How do you *actually* run a Snap package when your home directory isn't under /home?

Tags: mount, snap, home-directory

I have my home directory at `/z/home/$USER`, instead of at `/home/$USER`, so I can have it on ZFS.

This upsets Snap packages to no end. When I try and run them, they say:

> Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported. 
>   See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.

When I go to that URL, I get a workaround, but not one described in sufficient detail to actually implement:

> Snapd does currently not support running snaps if the home directory of the user is outside of /home. This is discussed here [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/3352).
>
> A workaround is to bind mount the home directory outside /home into /home.

The linked thread degenerates into discussion of what the design for properly supporting arbitrary home directories *ought* to be, and it is not immediately apparent to me how to implement the described workaround. I tried bind mounting `/z/home/$USER` to also appear at `/home/$USER`, and telling the Snap that that is my home directory, but my Snap package I want to run is still insisting that my home directory is bad and refusing to run:

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/$USER
$ sudo chown ${USER}:${USER} /home/$USER
$ sudo mount --bind /z/home/$USER /home/$USER
$ HOME=/home/$USER any-snap-package 
Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported. 
See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
```

How, exactly, does one go about implementing the workaround described by Michael Vogt in the linked Snapcraft forum thread? Or does the workaround not actually work?

Comment: Snaps can only access a limited set of directories for security reasons (they run in restricted container like environments). It's further complicated by which confinement policy they exist in ('strict', 'classic' or 'devmode' https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) Are you talking about a 'classic' confined snap? or 'strict'?  (I'm suspicious a strict confinement won't allow what you want to do, but alas I'm unsure).

Comment: The snap in question is `minetest`; it is whatever confinement the default is when installing from the software center (I believe `strict`).

Comment: I've had moderate success with the steps in this post: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-can-i-use-snap-when-i-dont-use-home-user/3352/20

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `snap` gets its information on where your home directory is straight from `/etc/passwd` and not from any other source. One workaround that I've been able to get mostly working involves using a Docker container to replace `/etc/passwd` from `snap`'s point of view, with one that says my home directory is `/home/$USER`.

I'm sure there's a lighter-weight way to do this (maybe just a chroot?) that would negate the need for some of the *other* workarounds I needed to get `snap` to work inside a container, and I haven't tried it with `minetest`, but here's the script I put together that runs the `teatime` Snap without me having to actually move my home directory. Basically it starts a container with `snapd` in it, with all the places that `snapd` keeps state mounted in from outside, but initialized with the base state of a freshly installed `snapd` (which is what it needs the `local-persist` Docker volume driver for). Then it runs `snap` in the container, as you, with all the X11 and DBUS plumbing wired up so that `teatime` can show its windows and desktop notifications.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# teatime.sh: Run the teatime snap in a Docker container
# Requires local-persist driver installed in Docker: https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist
# Installs it if not available.

set -ex

IMAGE_NAME="snapdock"
CONTAINER_NAME="snaphost"
STORAGE_ROOT="/var/lib/snapdock"
PASSWD_FILE="$HOME/etc/passwd.docker"

if [[ ! -f "${PASSWD_FILE}" ]] ; then
    # The /etc/passwd that claims we have a normal home directory doesn't exist.
    # We need to make it.
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "${PASSWD_FILE}")"

    cat "/etc/passwd" | sed "s_${HOME}_/home/${USER}_g" > "${PASSWD_FILE}"
fi


if ! (docker images "${IMAGE_NAME}" | grep "${IMAGE_NAME}" >/dev/null) ; then
    # There's no image ready. We need to make one
    WORKDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
    cd "${WORKDIR}"
    cat >Dockerfile <<EOF
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# Based on https://github.com/ogra1/snapd-docker/blob/master/build.sh
ENV container docker
ENV PATH "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q -y update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q -y upgrade && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q -y install \
        fuse \
        snapd \
        snap-confine \
        squashfuse \
        sudo && \
    apt-get clean && \
    dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/udevadm && \
    ln -s /bin/true /sbin/udevadm
VOLUME ["/sys/fs/cgroup"]
STOPSIGNAL SIGRTMIN+3
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
EOF
    docker build . -t "${IMAGE_NAME}"
    cd -
    rm -Rf "${WORKDIR}"
fi

if ! which docker-volume-local-persist >/dev/null ; then
    # We need the local-persist driver installed into Docker.

    WORKDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
    cd "${WORKDIR}"
    curl -fsSL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist/45c5c344d5dfd358c28d7148be48302d20456fac/scripts/install.sh" >install.sh
    chmod +x install.sh
    cat install.sh
    sudo install.sh
    cd -
    rm -Rf "${WORKDIR}"
fi

if ! (docker ps --filter "name=${CONTAINER_NAME}" | grep "${CONTAINER_NAME}" >/dev/null) ; then
    # Container is not running. Start it.

    if [[ ! -e "${STORAGE_ROOT}" ]] ; then
        # Make sure we have the directories to mount          
        mkdir -p "${STORAGE_ROOT}/lib"
        mkdir -p "${STORAGE_ROOT}/cache"
        mkdir -p "${STORAGE_ROOT}/systemd"
        mkdir -p "${STORAGE_ROOT}/snap"
        sudo chown -R root:root "${STORAGE_ROOT}"
    fi

    # Start the container
    docker run --rm --network=host --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined --security-opt seccomp:unconfined --volume="$(echo ~:/home/${USER})"  --volume="${PASSWD_FILE}:/etc/passwd:ro" --volume="/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" --volume="/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" --volume="/etc/sudoers.d:/etc/sudoers.d:ro" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" --volume="/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro" --volume="/lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro" --device=/dev/fuse --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock --volume="/run/user/$(id -u):/run/user/$(id -u):rw" --tmpfs /tmp --volume="${STORAGE_ROOT}/lib/:/var/lib/snapd:rw" --volume="${STORAGE_ROOT}/cache/:/var/cache/snapd:rw" --mount "type=volume,volume-driver=local-persist,src=installed-snaps-systemd,target=/etc/systemd/system,volume-opt=mountpoint=${STORAGE_ROOT}/systemd" --mount "type=volume,volume-driver=local-persist,src=installed-snaps-snap,target=/snap,volume-opt=mountpoint=${STORAGE_ROOT}/snap" -it --name="${CONTAINER_NAME}" -d "${IMAGE_NAME}" >/dev/null

    # Wait for it to come up
    sleep 5

fi

# Make sure the snap is installed
docker exec snaphost snap install teatime
# Try and fail to run it as root to avoid complaints about not being able to capture mountpoints when we run it as us.
docker exec snaphost teatime || true
# Run it as us with X11 and Dbus set up
docker exec -d --user="$(id -u ${USER})" --env="DISPLAY" --env="DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" snaphost teatime
```